# How to resolve "input ConnectedServiceName expects a service connection of type AzureRM" error?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I am learning how to create azure pipeline and ran into the following error:

> The pipeline is not valid. Job Phase_1: Step
> AzureResourceGroupDeployment input ConnectedServiceName expects a
> service connection of type AzureRM but the provided service connection
> "MY-SERVICE-CONNECTION-NAME" is of type generic.

[image]

What am I missing here?

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - cosmos
  batch: True
jobs:
- job: Phase_1
  displayName: Phase 1
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
    displayName: Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on DISPLAY-NAME
    inputs:
      # azureSubscription: 'SUBSCRIPTION'
      ConnectedServiceName: MY-SERVICE-CONNECTION-NAME
      resourceGroupName: DISPLAY-NAME
      location: West US # TBD
      csmFile: cosmos/deploy.json
      csmParametersFile: cosmos/parameters-dev.json
      deploymentName: DEPLOYMENT-NAME
```

I tried values from "service connections" but not sure what is the issue here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue:

[image]

As Daniel said, this is caused by the service connection type.

From this document you can know what the parameters are:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2/README.md#parameters-of-the-task

Share a little trick. Can help you avoid this type of problem in the future. When you type '- task: sometask@version' in the correct place of YML file of the pipeline in DevOps, you will see a 'Settings' button in the upper left, click it and you can set the value through the UI, which can filter the appropriate options for you:

[image]

Comment: I tried that as well, but I was getting `You do not have permission to create a service connection. You need to be a Creator for service connections in this project` error. After working with DevOps team, I was able to get the connection value and it resolved the issue. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @GThree Contact the devops admin so that you can get the permission required.

Comment: That what I did to fix the issue (mentioned in last comment).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you the exact problem. Your service connection needs to be an Azure Resource Manager service connection. Create a service connection of the appropriate type.

Comment: Turned out I had to get that from my DevOps team. I did not have that permission (tried the approach which was suggested by Bowman above). Once I had the token, I was able to resolve the issue.